# Whith what texture can I combine AO?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I want to bake AO and I heard I can integrate it in other texture.

With what texture can I combine AO?

What I'm trying to say is that I want to bake a combined texture that contain AO .

Comment: and where did you hear it?

Comment: I can't remember, but ,this is true ?

Comment: and already searched in google to see if you find where you read it?

Comment: of course I searched

Comment: You can combine it with your diffuse map? Color and darkness value combined.